# Listing the Files in a Directory in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, directory-listing

I have tried to "simplify" a nice piece of example code, the hyperlink to the code is at the end of this message, to specify the directory string instead of passing it as a command line argument. The simplified code compiles and executes, but the filename and size are not what I expect: the file name appears to be a hex number, and the nFileSize.High is larger than the nFileSize.Low (the actual file sizes range from 0 to 100Mb).  I think my type casting may have introduced errors.  Any suggestions?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
using namespace std; 
using namespace System;  //set common language runtime support to /clr

int main()
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
   LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
   //TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
   //size_t length_of_arg;
   HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   //DWORD dwError=0;

    finstr = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Data Analysis\\Data Folder\\*";

   //Just evaluate the first file before looping over all files
   hFind = FindFirstFile((wchar_t*)(finstr.c_str()), &ffd);

   wstring wsfname(ffd.cFileName);
   string newtemp(wsfname.begin(), wsfname.end());
   cout << "1st fname = " << ffd.cFileName << "   newtemp = "<< newtemp << "   nFSizeLo = "<< ffd.nFileSizeLow << "   nFSizeHi = "<< ffd.nFileSizeHigh << "\n";

   FindClose(hFind);
   return 0;
}
```

Link to original example from Microsoft

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(d=printer,v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think you have a problem among string conversions.

Comment: Try: **1.** `wstring wsfname( CT2A(ffd.cFileName, CP_UTF8));` **2.** Delete the next line **3.** Replace `cout` by `wcout` and use `wsfname` instead.

Comment: Make it `wstring finstr = L"C:\\Users...";` (note `L` prefix) and drop the cast in `FindFirstFile` call: `FindFirstFile(finstr.c_str(), &ffd)`. In general, avoid mixing and matching narrow and wide strings; stick with Unicode wherever possible. Your `FindFirstFile` call fails, but you don't know that because you aren't checking its return value. You then examine random garbage that happens to be in the uninitialized `ffd`